# In PHP, how to decompress a file on the fly that was compressed twice?

Tags: php, gzip, zlib

I have a `bigfile.gz.gz` file that is… big. I would like to uncompress it on the fly. Ideally, this is what I have in mind:

```
$in = fopen('compress.zlib://compress.zlib://bigfile.gz.gz', 'rb');
while (!feof($in))
    print fread($in, 4096);
fclose($in);
```

However, `compress.zlib://` cannot be chained that way:

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(): cannot represent a stream of type ZLIB as a File Descriptor in gztest.php on line 1
```

So I thought I’d combine `gzopen()` and `compress.zlib://` together:

```
$in = gzopen('compress.zlib://bigfile.gz.gz', 'rb');
while (!gzeof($in))
    print gzread($in, 4096);
gzclose($in);
```

However, this only decompresses one level of gzip.

I tried probably 10 other methods, unfortunately `gzopen()` does not work with `php://memory` if it’s been written to using `fwrite()`. And `stream_filter_append(… zlib.inflate …)` cannot read gzipped files.

This is the best I could come up with, but it spawns two system processes, which has undesirable overhead:

```
$in = popen('zcat bigfile.gz.gz | gunzip', 'rb');
while (!feof($in))
    print fread($in, 4096);
fclose($in);
```

Can someone suggest something better maybe?

Comment: Why do you even compress it twice? Afaik, this isn't efficient because it costs more cpu than it actually compresses after the first round. Use a higher compression level first instead of compressing twice with average compression level.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Because `bigfile.gz` is 302 MiB whereas `bigfile.gz.gz` is only 22 MiB.

Comment: Ok, that was unexpected :)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to uncompress .gz files using the zlib.inflate filter. You just need to strip out the gzip header first. To do that on the fly, you have to deploy a custom filter:

```
<?php

class gzip_header_filter extends php_user_filter {

    private $filtered = 0;

    public function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing) {
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            if($this->filtered == 0) {
                $header_len = 10;
                $header = substr($bucket->data, 0, 10);
                $flags = ord($header[3]);
                if($flags & 0x08) {
                    // a filename is present
                    $header_len = strpos($bucket->data, "\0", 10) + 1;
                } 
                $bucket->data = substr($bucket->data, $header_len);
                $this->filtered = $header_len;
            }
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}

stream_filter_register('gzip_header_filter', 'gzip_header_filter');

$in = fopen('bigfile.gz.gz', 'rb');
stream_filter_append($in, 'gzip_header_filter', STREAM_FILTER_READ);
stream_filter_append($in, 'zlib.inflate', STREAM_FILTER_READ);
stream_filter_append($in, 'gzip_header_filter', STREAM_FILTER_READ);
stream_filter_append($in, 'zlib.inflate', STREAM_FILTER_READ);

while (!feof($in))
    print fread($in, 4096);
fclose($in);

?>
```

Note that the code above doesn't handle comments and other extra data that could be stored in the gz file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wanted to say that `gzip_header_filter` was not needed (you can just pass a value for `window` between `16` and `30` as an argument to the `zlib.inflate` filter, which will skip the gzip header), but using that filter actually works around [an apparent bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67724)